# How can I run my GUI application without desktop enviroment and make it fullscreen?

Tags: lightdm, qt, fullscreen

I run ubuntu 16.04 on Intel Celeron CPU.

```
Linux kevin-minipc 4.8.0-39-generic #42~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 20 15:06:07 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and I wrote a Qt appliction. When I run it in desktop environment, it's fullscreen.

Now, I want the system autologin and my application run fullscreen as an X client when system started without desktop environment.

So I made these changes:

1. add a file named `lightdm.conf` in `/etc/lightdm`：

   ```
   [Seat:*]
   user-session=myxclient
   autologin-user=kevin
   autologin-user-timeout=delay
   ```

   `kevin` is my system account.
2. add a file `myxclient.desktop` in `/usr/share/xsessions`:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=myapp
   Comment=myapp
   Exec=/home/kevin/myapp
   Icon=
   Type=Application
   ```

   `/home/kevin/myapp` is the path to my Qt application.

When I reboot and system have started, myapp will run without desktop, but it **IS NOT fullscreen**.
I tried to run other application in the .desktop file, like firefox, it's not fullscreen either.

So, how can I make it fullscreen? Some other ways are also acceptable. 
(It's better I don't have to change any configurations when I use the display of different size.)

And another question: Without desktop environment, can I use input program like ibus?

Answer (score 2):

This is specific to the application you run. Your application may accept parameters, e.g. --fullscreen or --window-size. However, fullscreen is depended on the window manager, so if you only have display manager (LightDM) without a window manager, it is better simply set application window size across the entire screen size.

In addition, I am not running application as a session defined in the LightDM configuration file, but I have it defined in the ~/.xsession file. By default LightDM without window manager executes xterm. When you have ~/.xsession file it is executed instead of xterm.

For example, I have a kiosk with a chromium browser that I start with

```
chromium --app=https://example.com --window-position=0,0 --window-size=1920,1080
```

If your application does not support window position and size, you can resize with xdotool (the xdotool package on Debian), which requires some scripting.
After starting the application, you must first get a visible window number with

```
xdotool search --onlyvisible --maxdepth 1 ""
```

And next move and resize window with

```
xdotool windowmove {window_number} {posx} {posy} windowsize {window_num} {sizex} {sizey}
```